# Get-DscConfigurationStatus Invalid namespace

Tags: windows, powershell, configuration, dsc

I'm trying to execute some scripts that utilizes DSC and it seems to be failing pretty hard.
From all the documentation I've found, I believe I'm following the right steps and installing it, but clearly I've missed something. This is being executed in the Powershell ISE on Windows.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-DscConfigurationStatus
Get-DscConfigurationStatus : Invalid namespace 
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-DscConfigurationStatus
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager:root/Microsoft/...gurationManager) [Get-DscConfigurationSt 
   atus], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8004100e,Get-DscConfigurationStatus
```

I have both Powershell ISE and Powershell 7 (both are installed), and I understand DSC is different between Powershell versions as indicated here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/overview?view=dsc-2.0

I was attempting to follow this but something is really messed up with my DSC
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/getting-started/wingettingstarted?view=dsc-1.1

```
Install-Module 'PSDscResources' -Verbose
```

This installs fine and I have version 2.12.0.0 installed.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-InstalledModule PSDscResources

Version              Name                                Repository           Description                                                  
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------                                                  
2.12.0.0             PSDscResources                      PSGallery            This module contains the standard DSC resources.
```

I feel like this mismatch of versions is very correlated, but I'm pretty confused on what I should be using.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Install-Module -Name PSDesiredStateConfiguration
WARNING: Version '1.1' of module 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration' is already installed at 'C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\P
SDesiredStateConfiguration'. To install version '2.0.7', run Install-Module and add the -Force parameter, this command will install version 
'2.0.7' side-by-side with version '1.1'.
```

What am I setting up incorrectly here?

Comment: Have you tried running Install-Module -Name PSDesiredStateConfiguration -Force? This should solve your issue.

Comment: Yes - while it runs and I get past the last error of mismatched versions (because it forces the install of PSDesiredStateConfiguration) and it installs that package, the root issue of  Get-DscConfigurationStatus having an invalid namespace still occurs

Comment: On what OS are you working? I am failing to reproduce the error.

Comment: I am working in Windows 10